# How do I write a validation rule for a Date/Time field that only allows choosing M-F and 8am-5PM

Tags: formula, validation-rule

I have tried using the formula below:

```
NOT(
  AND(
    WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) >= 2,
    WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) <= 6,
    HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) >= 6,
    HOUR(TIMEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) < 20
  )
)
```

I haven't been working with validation rules for very long. I have spent time between yesterday and today trying to research my problem and am still no closer to a solution. Any suggestions would help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Validation rules trigger when they evaluate to true. As such, you need to write the rule such that the *illegal* values return true. Your validation rule looks fine, you just need to invert the output:

```
NOT(
  AND(
    WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) >= 2,
    WEEKDAY(DATEVALUE(Date_Time_Test__c)) <= 6,
    HOUR(Date_Time_Test__c) >= 8,
    HOUR(Date_Time_Test__c) < 17
  )
)
```

Keep in mind that these values will be calculated using the user's time zone settings.

Comment: I get a syntax error when I try my validation rule: 
 Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'WEEKDAY()'. Expected Date, received DateTime

Comment: @nprevallet You'll need to add `DATEVALUE` to the formula. I've added that in.

Comment: I got passed the exception with your assist, so thanks there. I ran into another exception stating 'HOUR()', Expected Time, received DateTime. So, I added in ```TIMEVALUE``` and got passed that exception as well. Now, no matter how I change my signs for evaluating the time, my expected behavior is not happening. Thoughts?